# View css styles in a demo page

Tags: css

Is there an app out there that will take a .css file and output a demo page of it?

Like take all the span/div/a elements and display what they would look like in an html page?

Comment: Came upon this question and wanted to add a use case. I'm just coming into a project with very robust stylesheets in place (compass if it matters). I'm putting in a link, and want to style it according to the mocks, so I have to search the site and find a similar link to capture the class.

Granted, a good style guide, organization, and documentation could render the problem moot, but what I really want is an auto-updating page (or app) which just renders all the classes with their names. I can look down the list, find my link style, and plug it in.

Comment: @atonyc - In my opinion that's backwards; I wouldn't modify the structure or the [element identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) in the HTML to cater to a CSS style sheet - I'd leverage the power of CSS selectors and design my stylesheet to work with my HTML. To me, editing your HTML so you can "capture the class" is like rebuilding the frame of your car so you can use a particular brand of paint!  Remember that content is king, not stylesheets ;)

Answer (score 2):

... without an associated (X)HTML file?

If what you need to do involves CSS with no knowledge of its associated (X)HTML document's structure or classes or ids... then isn't it simple enough to just write up a small page and preview it in a browser?

Not to offend, but personally I think previewing CSS without an (X)HTML document is a little strange. A few reasons:

If you start with CSS you may try to make your HTML cater to your CSS when it should be the other way around.
Starting with the CSS and then writing your page feels like a good way to end up with messy HTML, and if I have to choose between (messy HTML and clean CSS) or (clean HTML and messy CSS) I personally would choose the clean HTML every time.

You also mention targeting `<div>` and `<span>`. This is a personal opinion, but I feel pretty strongly that people shouldn't target `<div>` and `<span>` without class or id attributes. Since `<div>` and `<span>` don't have semantic meaning, I just can't imagine why you'd need to style them unless you were either CSS resetting or fullfilling a requirement, and is your customer more likely to ask for "all employee names should be underlined" or "spans should be underlined"?
... but once you're targeting class and id, you need your HTML document to go with your CSS.

Comment: Agree with all this, curious what you have to say about the use case I commented in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

While this will not autogenerate anything from your css, this is an excellent XHTML test page that includes all of the standard tags, page, and form elements you are likely to have used.  Apply your style sheet to this page and you will be 80% of the way there.  Then just add areas for your custom classes, etc.  http://snipplr.com/view/8121/html-test-page-for-css-style-guide

Answer (score 0):

TopStyle does that with an internal view. It is an excellent tool.

http://www.topstyle4.com/

Comment: Click the link, second link on the left says "Screenshots". Look at the bottom of the IDE. The styles-as-HTML panel is expandable and can be anchored to any side of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendur: http://rendur.com/

I agree with Richard that you shouldn't expect much if you're styling raw div and span elements.  :)

Comment: I thought I was the only one! :D